# How to add first page and end page and pagination panel in two side of page

Tags: jquery, pagination

i'm using [JQuery pagination](http://tutorials.ajaxmasters.com/pagination-demo/) to paginate some div result.

What i've done is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       var optInit = getOptionsFromForm();
       $("#Pagination").pagination(<?php echo $num_result;?>, optInit);
    });
    function pageselectCallback(page_index, jq){
       var items_per_page = 10;
       var max_elem = Math.min((page_index+1) * items_per_page, <?php echo $num_result;?>);
        $('div[id^="page"]').hide();
        for(var i=page_index*items_per_page;i<max_elem;i++){
            $('#page'+i).show();
        }

        return false;
    }

    function getOptionsFromForm(){
       var opt = {callback: pageselectCallback,prev_text :'Pagina precedente',next_text:'Pagina successiva',num_display_entries:10,num:2};
       return opt;
    }

</script>

<div id="result_pagin">
   <?php for($i=0;$i<$num_result;$i++){?>
      <div id="page<?php echo $i;?>
         .
         .
         .
      </div>
   <?php }?>
</div>
<div id="Pagination" class="pagination">
</div>
```

What i need to do is to show pagination panel before result_pagin div and at the end, and i need to add, in that panel, first page and end page buttons. is possible? can someone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="Pagination" class="pagination">
  <a id="pgstart" href="#page1">Page 1</a>
  <a id="pgend></a>
</div>

<div id="result_pagin">
<!--...-->
</div>

<script>
  var pgend = (<?php echo $num_result;?> / 10);
  $("#pgend").attr("href", "#page"+pgend);
</script>
```